# how to get some of values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using the array below, I want to get just some value of an element containing a certain value for *option_name*. For example, I want to get the element with *option_name* => **custom_radio_gender** then the result will show the value of *option_value* for that element (i.e. **Radio 1**).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 15
            [user_id] => 3
            [option_name] => custom_monStart
            [option_value] => a:3:{i:0;s:8:"05:30 am";i:1;s:8:"07:30 am";i:2;s:8:"09:30 am";}
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 13
            [user_id] => 3
            [option_name] => custom_radio_gender
            [option_value] => Radio 1
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 14
            [user_id] => 3
            [option_name] => custom_time2
            [option_value] => 
            [autoload] => yes
        )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. In those questions learn how to properly provide a [mcve]. In your case, what have you tried?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a basic PHP question,which has nothing relationship with javascript.What you need is just a function like:

```
function getValue($array, $key){
    foreach($array as $content){
        if(array_key_exists("option_name", $content) && $content["option_name"] == $key){
            return $content["option_value"];
        }
    }
}
```